# Automatic login on startup - Ubuntu Studio 21.04 hirsute

Tags: login, automatic

I have been chasing "solutions" but have been unsuccessful, modifying various `.conf` files, etc.

Please point me in the right direction to have my Ubuntu Studio automatically login and launch the Anydesk, and Zoom Clients.

Comment: Please don't use autologin. It's a bad practice and quite counterproductive. You can add any software to the startup apps. Please do not modify system files you don't understand.

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask) :-)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am configuring decommissioned office computers to give to elderly and infirm friends. Just need them to power on the computer, thereafter I can connect and launch the applications so they can Zoom chat with others.
Thanks again.

Comment: "It's a bad practice and quite counterproductive" You need to explain that.

Comment: Anyone? Please?
Thank you.

Comment: @24601 Do I? It's pretty much written everywhere in any "best practices" manual or article. Even Windows now make it really hard for users to login without a password. And why it's quite counterproductive is also very easy to explain. Many things need access to the keyring (WiFi, etc.) and that requires the user password that when the user is logged properly automatically unlocks it but with autologin anything relying on the keyring will ask for the password over and over. So, in order to save the user from typing it ONCE then many simple tasks will then ask you to do just that times MANY.

Comment: Ubuntu Studio seems like the wrong desktop for "*configuring decommissioned office computers to give to elderly and infirm friends*"  Ubuntu Studio is intended for use by audio and video production professionals, and comes with those applications. It's not designed for general-purpose use.

Comment: @ChanganAuto be sure to differentiate opinion and experience from what is supported here. Gnome, for example, does have a use case and supporting tools for auto-login.  Personally I don't use it (opinion/experience), but it's there: It's not a hack, and we do indeed provide support for it.

Comment: @user535733 Still a bad practice irrespective of being supported (it is, I never said it wasn't) like so many other things that you *can* do but you *shouldn't*. But it being counterproductive is not a matter of opinion, it's demonstrable in the exact situations I mentioned before. And I agree entirely about Studio being the wrong, actually the worse, choice.

Comment: I've just been experimenting with ubuntu MATE 21.04 and so far very impressed with it's clean clear lines and I think that would be a more reasonable choice for you to consider. The facility exists to set programs to launch at boot time quite simply which might satisfy your need for this aspect.

Answer (score 1):

I've been experimenting with ubuntu MATE 21.04 and so far I'm very impressed with it's good clean clear and uncomplicated lines which are easy on the eye and ideally suited for inexperienced seniors. I think this would be a more reasonable choice for you to consider and perhaps more suited to the hardware you have in mind.

The facility exists to set programs to launch at boot time quite simply which might satisfy your need for this aspect.

[image]

The above application maybe launched from MATE Control Center or using `mate-session-properties` command.

I've not specifically tried this with Anydesk or Zoom clients but I don't see why it wouldn't work.

[This reference](https://guide.ubuntu-mate.org/) is the official ubuntu MATE guide

Comment: Thank you very much for recommending Ubuntu Mate. I will give it a try, with the hopes that I can successfully configure the OS to automatically login. Have you tried that feature on Ubuntu Mate?

Thanks again.

Comment: Yes I have the auto login set and it works perfectly well. A small administrative matter; if this his addressed your question please consider accepting and upvoting it as per [this guidance](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) Thanks.

Comment: You might also like to look at [Mate Community](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/welcome-to-the-ubuntu-mate-community/8)

Comment: G'Day @24601,
Many thanks for the recommendation. I am now running Mate on a different computer, and the automatic login works fine, I will be installing Zoom CLient and AnyDesk shortly.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: @BaronFerg excellent. Perhaps accept the answer in that case which will assist any others looking for a similar solution finding your post.

Comment: I want to but am not seeing any options to accept or VoteUp

Comment: music@music:~$ anydesk

(anydesk:41296): GdkGLExt-WARNING **: 08:03:27.471: Window system doesn't support OpenGL.

Can you comment on the above?
Thanks

Comment: @BaronFerg does [this link](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/installing-software/23978) offer any help? You seem to have unchecked the accept icon? The upvote is the grey uppointing arrow.

Comment: @BaronFerg regarding linking to the MATE PC see [this](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/how-to-allow-mate-to-accept-connection-with-remmina/23076/7) reference.